# Some keys not working on Musical Typing?

Tags: macos, midi, logic

I can't play some keys, such as H when on Octave C1, H and D when on Octave C2 or J and K on Octave C3. When I press them, I get no sound. If I manually place the notes out and then listen to it with Musical Typing open, it visually plays them.

Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Is this Garage Band? Logic Pro?

Comment: @Angelplayer Logic Pro, thought people could see it in the tags but maybe its not so obvious.

Comment: "logic" to most people has to do with the way we think.  Not a good way to tag a particular product.  Should be "logic-pro" or something.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem for over a year and I just fixed it! The fix was so simple, just press: Logic Pro X > Control Surfaces > Bypass All Control Surfaces.

Comment: Related https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT200260#PLIST_CS